# DAX set flag as max day per month and type

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have about a years worth of data. For each month, I want to set a flag = TRUE for the new IsMax calculated column if:

-Type 1 = FALSE

-Type2 = TRUE

-Quantity is the maximum after those first 2 conditions are met

Dataset:

[image]

Comment: What if there is a FALSE-FALSE on 9/6/2019, do you expect 9/7/2019 to be TRUE?

Comment: @Aldert that is actually not possible. Starting with the 1st day of every month, that day and the next 6 days will always be TYPE2 = TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first get the MAX of filtered rows with not Type1 && Type2 and then check all columns on that row.

```
IsMax = 
var maxQuantity = CALCULATE(MAX(myTable[Quantity]);FILTER(myTable;not myTable[Type1] && myTable[Type2]))
return not myTable[Type1] && myTable[Type2] && maxQuantity = myTable[Quantity]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

IsMax = 
var max_false_true= CALCULATE(max(SOLOW[Quantity]),ALL(SOLOW),SOLOW[Type1]=FALSE,SOLOW[Type2]=TRUE)
return
IF(AND(AND(SOLOW[Type1]=FALSE,SOLOW[Type2]=TRUE),SOLOW[Quantity]=max_false_true),TRUE,FALSE)

[Power BI Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSRW7.png)